# Favicon not working in Next.js _documents.js

Tags: next.js

This is the code in my _document.js:

```js
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

<html lang="id">
    <Head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../static/favicon.ico" />
    </Head>
    <body className="custom_class">
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
    </body>
</html>
```

I have confirmed that the favicon is in my static folder in my root directory: [image]

I've tried putting the head in index.js, moving the favicon in the public folder, and using a different icon. In my other Next.js projects, favicons also don't load. I've tried in Firefox, Edge, and Chrome. What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next.js serves static files from the `public` folder (it can't be changed). Files inside it can be referenced by your code starting from the base URL (`/`).

In your case you'll need to rename your `static` folder to `public` and then reference the favicon from your `_document` as:

```js
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```